# Netsh batch file

Tags: domain, batch-file

Is there way to join win7 to server 2008 by using netsh batch file ? 
I can change The IP , GateWay , Subnet Mask by bat file but How can I join domain

Answer (score 1):

There is `netdom` command. You can use it in batch files.

Comment: can you give me resource

Comment: Microsoft Technet article - http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc788049(v=ws.10).aspx